# Android - How to change fragments in the Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm fairly new to Android programming, but have been doing pretty well until now. I've read a lot of answers to this question but can't seem to make mine work. Basically what I have is a MainActivity with a Navigation Drawer. I have two fragments correctly initialized with corresponding fragment layout xmls. Currently I can get my first fragment to show up when the app starts and when I click on each item in the drawer, the titles change; however, the fragment stays the same. Any suggestions? What I believe to be relevant code is below (not shown is the code for the NavigationDrawerFragment.java with the necessary code automatically built by Eclipse). Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();

}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_infodirect);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_trailmap);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_poi);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_photomap);
            break;
        case 6:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_report);
            break;
        case 7:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_rulesreg);

    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overview, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

public static class InfoDirectFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static InfoDirectFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        InfoDirectFragment fragment = new InfoDirectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public InfoDirectFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infodirect, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I saw this link a few days ago, but was hesitant to follow it through because it would require changing almost all of my code. Since you suggested it, I decided I might as well try it out. Turns out it works great and was well worth changing my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow This [link!!](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) for more details and  use

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    switch (position) {

    case 0:

        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1, Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();

        break;


    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2, Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT);

        ft.commit();
        break;

    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(title[position]);

    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (position == 0) {  
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction() 
             .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance())  
             .commit();  
    } else if (position == 1) {  
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()  
         .replace(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())  
         .commit();  
    } else if (position == 2) {  
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()  
         .replace(R.id.container, ThridFragment.newInstance())  
         .commit();  
    }  

}
```

and create fragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {  

   public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
     FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();  
     return fragment;  
   }  

   public FirstFragment() {  
   }  

   @Override  
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);  
       return rootView;  
   }  

   @Override  
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {  
       super.onAttach(activity);  
       ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(1);  
   }  
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but my FirstFragment doesn't load the layout !!

Answer (score 4):

I was working with the Navigation Drawer based on what Eclipse generated as well (yours looks like it was made with it as well), and I've pruned it a bit so that it's not perfectly silly. I also did some black magic at some points, because I was getting silly errors that I've fixed over times (such as being unable to update the action bar title on Back press, or that if you rotate the screen then the element at index 0 is recreated by the activity):

NavigationDrawerActivity:

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getString(R.string.drawer_0);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
    {
        public void onBackStackChanged()
        {
            int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backCount == 0)
            {
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                mTitle = getString(((GetActionBarTitle) fragment).getActionBarTitleId());
                restoreActionBar();
            }
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        this.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar()
{
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
    {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
{
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean addToBackStack = true;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment0();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
        case 5:
            logout();
        default:
            Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Reached Default in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected!");
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null)
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        if (addToBackStack == true)
        {
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        ft.commit();
        mTitle = getString(((GetActionBarTitle) fragment).getActionBarTitleId());
        restoreActionBar();
    }
}

public void logout()
{
    this.finish();
}


}
```

The insidious "GetActionBarTitle":

```
 public interface GetActionBarTitle
 {
     public int getActionBarTitleId();
 }
```

The generated NavigationDrawerFragment (I don't think I've changed this at all):

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment
{

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually expands
 * it. This shared
 * preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment()
{
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container,
            false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    String[] drawerTitles = new String[] { getString(R.string.drawer_0),
            getString(R.string.drawer_1),
            getString(R.string.drawer_2), getString(R.string.drawer_3),
            getString(R.string.drawer_4), getString(R.string.drawer_5) };
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, drawerTitles));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen()
{
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 * 
 * @param fragmentId
 *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout
 *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
{
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded())
            {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded())
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer)
            {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
    {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position)
{
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null)
    {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null)
    {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null)
    {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen())
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example)
     * {
     * Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     * return true;
     * }
     */

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than
 * just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar()
{
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar()
{
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
}
```

An example fragment that is created by this navigation drawer:

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements GetActionBarTitle, OnClickListener
{
private int titleId;
private Button btn0;
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;

public MyFragment()
{
    super();
    titleId = R.string.drawer_myfragment_title;
}

@Override
public int getActionBarTitleId()
{
    return titleId;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btn0 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn0);
    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (btn0 == v)
    {

    }
    else if (btn1 == v)
    {

    }
    else if (btn2 == v)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I hope that works as you intended. I had to do magic with the BackStackListener and stuff to work properly.

Comment: good work. But if I want to open a fragment once a time. If again same title from navigation drawer is selected then it should use fragment that is opened before.

Comment: @BSKANIA Yeah, although I haven't had that figured out. I'm guessing I should keep track of them and essentially reimplement the FragmentPagerAdapter or the FragmentStatePagerAdapter in terms of functionality, and I haven't had that figured out, and I never needed to finish it.

Comment: @BSKANIA it actually shouldn't be that hard however, as considering I store the data in the backstack, it can be accessed with the fragment backstack entry ID `FragmentManager#getBackStackEntryAt(int)` and `FragmentManager#getBackStackEntry()`. It is important to note that after you rotate the screen, it calls upon display(0) and that is why I call onBackPressed(), but that would need to be changed to just display the current Fragment rather than 0.. that needs black magic if orientation change is allowed. However, other than that, I didn't need to implement this, but this is the start.

Comment: currently this is what I am using to handle backstack.https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

Comment: @BSKANIA while you *can* do that, I'm not sure what he means by Android not managing them. That's what the `addToBackStack(null)` call is for.

Comment: I am not using this for handling backpress event but mainly not to call single fragment more that one time if called again.  So for backpressed your example is good. But I am finding solution for not to assign same fragment again.

Answer (score 3):

I  know this is quite old, but I would like to share some articles Ive written about the Application Drawer and Fragment navigation. They are up to date with the latest samples (as for 2017 at least). Feel free to take a look at:

https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/android-tutorial-drawer-and-fragment-navigation-made-easyier/

https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/14/android-drawer-and-fragment-navigation-a-more-real-life-scenario/