# Tab Layout with a Navigation Drawer and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I've been trying to get back into something I was working on before and got stuck on. I found a picture on the google developers site that has what I'm trying to create.

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B9PCOJnbdRP6QW9pN01mS2k4UFU/patterns_navigation_twolevel4.png

Basically, I have one activity, that has several fragments that you can navigate to through the navigation drawer that pulls out from the side. I'm trying to have one of those fragments be a fragment that has a tabbed layout, which works fine, except the tabs don't show up since the toolbar created in the activity. How do i do this?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006181/android-how-to-change-fragments-in-the-navigation-drawer

Comment: The fragments themselves I are changing fine through the nav drawer, and the tabs in the one fragment that I am using them in swipe fine from the viewhandler. It's just the tab listing that doesn't show up at all on the toolbar.